# Prove that det(A)=0 when ak , the k-th row vector of A, is equal to λ ai + µ aj , where ai , aj ∈ R^n

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, determinant

Hi can anybody help me with this problem?

Let A be an n × n matrix, let i, j, k be pairwise distinct indices, 1 ≤ i, j, k ≤ n,
and let λ, µ ∈ R be arbitrary real numbers. Suppose that ak
, the k-th row vector of A,
is equal to λ ai + µ aj
, where ai
, aj ∈ R^n denote the i-th and the j-th row vectors of A
respectively. 
Prove that det(A) = 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may know that:

- the determinant doesn't change when you add a multiple of a row (or column) to another row (or column);
- the determinant of a matrix with a row (or column) full of zeros, is $0$ (you can expand along this row/column).

**Hint**: with the information given in your question: subtract $\lambda$ times the $i$th row and $\mu$ times the $j$th row from the $k$th row.

Comment: Thanks a lot, done it now!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Since the $k^{th}$ row of $A$ is a linear combination of the $i^{th}$ row and $j^{th}$ row so $\text{Rank A}<n$ and hence $\det A=0$

Comment: Thanks :) I've finished the question now